# Webpack&TypeScript: require() с переменной в качестве аргумента, случай с алиасом

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

Как известно, в Webpack нельзя так просто подставлять переменную в качестве аргумента `require()`. Прочитал кучу обсуждений на эту тему и, честно говоря, так и не понял, как решить эту проблему. Конкретно в моём случае необходимо не просто сделать аргумент `require()` переменной, а ещё и при этом путь, который является значением переменной, содержит алиас (в данном примере - `projectOpenScripts`):

```
export default class Resources {

  constructor(pathToResourcesFile: string){

    // true
    console.log(pathToResourcesFile === 'projectOpenScripts/resources/resources.json5') 

    // works
    let parsedResources = require('projectOpenScripts/resources/resources.json5'); 

    // does not work
    let parsedResources = require(pathToResourcesFile);
    console.log(parsedResources.c)
  }
}
```

Я использую `TypeScript`, потому у меня алиасы объявлены не только в **webpack.config.js**, но и в **tsconfig.json**:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    // ...

    "baseUrl": "./",
      "projectOpenScripts": ["development/1_Source/1_open/3_scripts"]
    },

    "types": [
      // Need for require() and require.ensure
      "webpack-env"
    ]
  }
}
```

Помимо решения данной проблемы, необходимо что-то сделать с предупреждением `Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression` от компилятора TypeScript.

Не могу поверить, что это проблему нельзя решить. Ведь такие ограничения, как "нельзя подставлять переменную в качестве аргумента require()" противоречат концепции программирования.

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/ ©A context is created if your request contains expressions, so the exact module is not known on compile time.

Comment: О каких концепциях Вы говорите?? `require` это синтаксический сахар поверх `Module._load` и обертка поверх `Module.require`, если говорить в контексте `node.js`, он синхронный и кеширует все модули на этапе компиляции, поэтому просто так где-то в рантайме сделать `require(variable)` не получится, он не знает где искать этот модуль, точнее он пытается найти модуль в `Module._cache` и кидает эксепшн `Cannot find module`. Используйте динамический `import`

Comment: @overthesanity, благодарю Вас за объяснение! Динамический импорт _в данном случае_ неприятен тем, что он даёт дополнительный JavaScript-файл, который чтобы загрузить, webpack создаст в head дополнительный скрипт и асинхронно подгрузит его. Это прекрасно в тех случаях, когда какой-то функционал нужно подгрузить в зависимости от определённого условия, но в моём случае подгрузка происходит всегда, следовательно превращение Data.json в отдельный динамический подгружаемый модуль не обоснованно. Походу придётся сделать аргументом сам файл Data.json ...

Comment: кстати насчёт `Я использую TypeScript, потому у меня алиасы объявлены не только в webpack.config.js, но и в tsconfig.json` : https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin